Compilation error using @tensorflow/tfjs-node in Scratch3 development
I am working on building an extension for Scratch3 to do machine learning using tensorflow.js. I forked out a repo from here. When I try to start, it ran into compilation error.
Environment details:

Ubuntu-22.04 on WSL2
node version v21.7.1
yarn version 1.22.22
npm version 10.5.0

Detailed steps are as follows:

cd scratch-vm && yarn add @tensorflow/tfjs-node
yarn install && yarn link
cd ../scratch-gui && yarn link scratch-vm && yarn install
Add this line in scratch-vm/src/extensions/scratch3_video_sensing/index.js 
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
cd to scratch_gui
yarn start

This is my package.json in scratch-vm:
{
  "name": "scratch-vm",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "Virtual Machine for Scratch 3.0",
  "author": "Massachusetts Institute of Technology",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/LLK/scratch-vm#readme",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@github.com/LLK/scratch-vm.git"
  },
  "main": "./dist/node/scratch-vm.js",
  "browser": "./src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run docs && webpack --progress --colors --bail",
    "coverage": "tap ./test/{unit,integration}/*.js --coverage --coverage-report=lcov",
    "deploy": "touch playground/.nojekyll && gh-pages -t -d playground -m \"Build for $(git log --pretty=format:%H -n1)\"",
    "docs": "jsdoc -c .jsdoc.json",
    "i18n:src": "mkdirp translations/core && format-message extract --out-file translations/core/en.json src/extensions/**/index.js",
    "i18n:push": "tx-push-src scratch-editor extensions translations/core/en.json",
    "lint": "eslint . && format-message lint src/**/*.js",
    "prepublish": "in-publish && npm run build || not-in-publish",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "tap": "tap ./test/{unit,integration}/*.js",
    "tap:unit": "tap ./test/unit/*.js",
    "tap:integration": "tap ./test/integration/*.js",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run docs && npm run tap",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --colors --watch",
    "version": "json -f package.json -I -e \"this.repository.sha = '$(git log -n1 --pretty=format:%H)'\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^4.17.0",
    "@vernier/godirect": "1.5.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.3",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.4",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.15",
    "arraybuffer-loader": "^1.0.6",
    "atob": "2.1.2",
    "btoa": "1.2.1",
    "canvas-toBlob": "1.0.0",
    "decode-html": "2.0.0",
    "diff-match-patch": "1.0.4",
    "format-message": "6.2.1",
    "graphql": "^14.5.3",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "htmlparser2": "3.10.0",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "minilog": "3.1.0",
    "nets": "3.2.0",
    "scratch-parser": "5.0.0",
    "scratch-sb1-converter": "0.2.7",
    "scratch-translate-extension-languages": "0.0.20190416132834",
    "socket.io-client": "2.0.4",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "text-encoding": "0.7.0",
    "worker-loader": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "adm-zip": "0.4.11",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.4",
    "docdash": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-scratch": "^5.0.0",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.5",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "format-message-cli": "6.2.0",
    "gh-pages": "^1.2.0",
    "in-publish": "^2.0.0",
    "jsdoc": "^3.5.5",
    "json": "^10.0.0",
    "lodash.defaultsdeep": "4.6.1",
    "pngjs": "^3.3.2",
    "scratch-audio": "^0.1.0-prerelease.20200528195344",
    "scratch-blocks": "^0.1.0-prerelease.20200804140007",
    "scratch-l10n": "^3.1.20181129221712",
    "scratch-render": "^0.1.0-prerelease.20200806013734",
    "scratch-storage": "^1.1.0",
    "scratch-svg-renderer": "^0.2.0-prerelease.20200610220938",
    "script-loader": "0.7.2",
    "stats.js": "^0.17.0",
    "tap": "^12.0.1",
    "tiny-worker": "^2.1.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.2.7",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  }
}


This is my package.json in scratch-gui:
{
  "name": "scratch-gui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "GraphicaL User Interface for creating and running Scratch 3.0 projects",
  "main": "./dist/scratch-gui.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack --progress --colors --bail",
    "clean": "rimraf ./build && mkdirp build && rimraf ./dist && mkdirp dist",
    "deploy": "touch build/.nojekyll && gh-pages -t -d build -m \"Build for $(git log --pretty=format:%H -n1)\"",
    "prune": "./prune-gh-pages.sh",
    "i18n:push": "tx-push-src scratch-editor interface translations/en.json",
    "i18n:src": "rimraf ./translations/messages/src && babel src > tmp.js && rimraf tmp.js && build-i18n-src ./translations/messages/src ./translations/ && npm run i18n:push",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "npm run test:lint && npm run test:unit && npm run build && npm run test:integration",
    "test:integration": "jest --runInBand test[\\\\/]integration",
    "test:lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx",
    "test:unit": "jest test[\\\\/]unit",
    "test:smoke": "jest --runInBand test[\\\\/]smoke",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --colors --watch"
  },
  "author": "Massachusetts Institute of Technology",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/LLK/scratch-gui#readme",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@github.com/LLK/scratch-gui.git"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "arraybuffer-loader": "^1.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.0.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "base64-loader": "1.0.0",
    "bowser": "1.9.4",
    "chromedriver": "76.0.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "computed-style-to-inline-style": "3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.5.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.3.0",
    "es6-object-assign": "1.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-config-scratch": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.14.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "get-float-time-domain-data": "0.1.0",
    "get-user-media-promise": "1.1.4",
    "gh-pages": "github:rschamp/gh-pages#publish-branch-to-subfolder",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "immutable": "3.8.2",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jest": "^21.0.0",
    "js-base64": "2.4.9",
    "keymirror": "0.1.1",
    "lodash.bindall": "4.4.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "4.0.8",
    "lodash.defaultsdeep": "4.6.0",
    "lodash.isequal": "4.5.0",
    "lodash.omit": "4.5.0",
    "lodash.pick": "4.4.0",
    "lodash.throttle": "4.0.1",
    "minilog": "3.1.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "omggif": "1.0.9",
    "papaparse": "4.6.2",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^5.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "query-string": "^5.1.1",
    "raf": "^3.4.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-contextmenu": "2.9.4",
    "react-dom": "16.2.0",
    "react-draggable": "3.0.5",
    "react-ga": "2.5.3",
    "react-intl": "2.9.0",
    "react-modal": "3.9.1",
    "react-popover": "0.5.10",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-responsive": "5.0.0",
    "react-style-proptype": "3.2.2",
    "react-tabs": "2.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0",
    "react-tooltip": "3.8.0",
    "react-virtualized": "9.20.1",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3",
    "redux-throttle": "0.1.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "scratch-audio": "0.1.0-prerelease.20190114210212",
    "scratch-blocks": "0.1.0-prerelease.1568071968",
    "scratch-l10n": "3.5.20190827223456",
    "scratch-paint": "0.2.0-prerelease.20190822205009",
    "scratch-render": "0.1.0-prerelease.20190904212449",
    "scratch-storage": "1.3.2",
    "scratch-svg-renderer": "0.2.0-prerelease.20201019174008",
    "scratch-vm": "0.2.0-prerelease.20190822194548",
    "selenium-webdriver": "3.6.0",
    "startaudiocontext": "1.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "svg-to-image": "1.1.3",
    "text-encoding": "0.7.0",
    "to-style": "1.3.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "wav-encoder": "1.3.0",
    "web-audio-test-api": "^0.5.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3",
    "xhr": "2.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "raf/polyfill",
      "<rootDir>/test/helpers/enzyme-setup.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "src/test.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/test/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/test/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  }
}

These are the error messages: 
Error_1 
Error_2 
Error_3 
Tried solutions:

Use 'webpack-node-externals' in scratch-vm/webpack.config.js
Remove node_modules and yarn.lock from both scratch-vm and scratch-gui then run yarn install again
cd into scratch-vm/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node and run npm install
Remove this line from index.js 
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')

1, 2 and 3 didn't change anything.
When I do 4, compilation is successful when I do yarn start in scratch-gui folder. However, I cannot use functions and methods like tf.node.decodePng().
